# How can I have an email link on a web page open in gmail instead of outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email

How can I have an email link on a web page open in gmail instead of outlook? Also, is it possible to have your browser (in this case Firefox) setup so that it will list a bunch of email clients when you click an email link on a page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox - Tools/Options/Applications/mailto/"use googlemail"

Answer (score 2):

**[Set Firefox 3 to Launch Gmail for mailto Links](http://lifehacker.com/392287/set-firefox-3-to-launch-gmail-for-mailto-links)**

Answer (score 2):

Use [GMail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html).  When you go through the installer you'll have the option to "use GMail for all mailto: links" and it will just work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous, so here are two answers:

If you're the **user** of the link:
The Firefox answers that have already been posted are good if you want to control what happens when *you* click on mailto links on *your* computer.

If you're the **author** of the link:
You can't write a link on web page in such a way that when a user clicks the link, it will open using a specific application - that's determined by the user and whatever applications and settings he has set up.