# How to open "mailto:" links in web-based email?

Tags: email, gmail, microsoft-outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have an email link on a web page open in gmail instead of outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/48129/how-can-i-have-an-email-link-on-a-web-page-open-in-gmail-instead-of-outlook)

Is there a way to have "mail to:" links open through a Gmail account in Chrome? My Microsoft Office is not set up. I'd rather keep it that way!

And, Gentlemen, I wish to thank you in advance for any and all assistance you might provide me and the presumed legions of future readers with the same question who will stumble upon this in their search for enlightenment.

Comment: There's also other options: http://superuser.com/search?q=%2Bgmail+%5Bgoogle-chrome%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several extensions for chrome to do this, pick the one you like the most:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?q=mailto